# How to wait for asp.net core configuration to be done for backgroundworkers?

Tags: asp.net-core, background-service

I created a blazor server application which also makes use of `BackgroundService` / `IHostedService` -  Unfortunately those services Start+Execute before the `Configure` method within `Startup` is called. Therefore migrations/database creation are not done before they are used in the services.

I already found a workaround for this, but i am wondering if there is a proper way to solve this.

My workaround for those who have the same issue is this:

```
public class ApplicationStateTransmitter
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource _configurationDone;

    public ApplicationStateTransmitter()
    {
        _configurationDone = new TaskCompletionSource(null);
    }

    public Task ConfigurationDone => _configurationDone.Task;

    public void NotifyConfigurationDone() => _configurationDone.SetResult();
}
```

Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSingleton<ApplicationStateTransmitter>();
```

Startup.Configure:

```
using (var serviceScope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    using (var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
    {
        if (!context.Database.CanConnect())
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Database does not exist yet - Creating database through migrations");
            context.Database.Migrate();
        }
        else
        {
            if (context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
            {
                logger.LogInformation("Applying database migration");
                context.Database.Migrate();
                logger.LogInformation("Applying database migration done");
            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogDebug("No pending migrations found");
            }
        }
    }
}

applicationStateTransmitter.NotifyConfigurationDone();

logger.LogInformation("Configuration done");
```

Inject instance and await like this

```
await _applicationStateTransmitter.ConfigurationDone;
```

Comment: Hi @Dbl, you mean the background services called the method before calling Configure method which is in Startup.cs? I have tested a official sample, and it will call Configure method first then call Start method which is in background services. Just do like the official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#ihostedservice-interface

Comment: Yes - I am talking about the Configure method within Startup.cs